# Why is my Facebook page automatically redirecting to external site?

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-page, facebook-timeline

I have a website: www.coversfm.com

I made a Facebook page for it: https://www.facebook.com/pages/Covers-FM/139507146178187

When I go to the FB page, I see a yellow message box:

"This is the administration interface for your webpage at http://www.coversfm.com/. You can see Insights and publish to the users that have liked your webpage. Only the administrators of the webpage can view this interface, other users are sent to the webpage."

So when other people (non-admins) Like this page or click through from the newsfeed, they get automatically redirected out to the external site - so the Facebook Page (timeline for Covers FM) never gets seen by anyone except me.

To further confuse things, in the page's settings, I see options such as "Everyone can post to Covers FM's timeline" - suggesting that regular users should in fact be able to access the timeline view??

How can I fix this? I want to have a Page/Timeline presence on Facebook!

Thanks.

Comment: also, in the Page admin settings, there is nowhere that my external URL is configured. Weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution, although rather frustratingly only after I'd created a new page, merged the Likes from the old one, losing all the old Page's posts. What I SHOULD have done is this:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/migration/

Basically, as CBroe alluded to, the recent Like migration enables you to migrate an external Like into an internal Like (ie. a real FB page that people can see and post to etc.).

1. Go to the Advanced settings for the associated app ID.
2. Enable the "External Page Migration" setting
3. Go to my page, and now see a pink Migrate Page box, rather than the yellow box i mentioned above.

Very annoying. Not massive amounts of content lost, but just need to start building up the page with a few posts, prof pic, cover pic etc.

Oh well, mystery solved. Hope it helps someone else!

Answer (score 2):

Did you set up this page yourself, or was it automatically created by Facebook?

> "This is the administration interface for your webpage at http://www.coversfm.com/. You can see Insights and publish to the users that have liked your webpage. […]"

The latter is not even possible any more nowadays, with the recent like migration.

---

The Graph API shows for your page,

```
"app_id": 106418287839
```

and for that app id then again,

```
"link": "https://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=106418287839"
```

– and visiting that link shows a Facebook message,

> You are being redirected to the Covers FM web app.

So all of that makes me think, that you did not set up a “normal” fan page, but that this is rather something auto-created by Facebook (an app page maybe), like they did some time ago.

Look into the admin menu of your page, if you can change the type of page to something else there. If not, try creating a new, “real” fan page – and see afterwards, if you can merge your existing page with that, to keep the existing likes.

Comment: This is starting to make sense. I did at one point, merge the manually created Page with all the likes for my main URL (www.coversfm.com) - this must be what triggered the external link association.